# How to setup an LDAP login with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ldap

I was asked to setup an ldap login for my web application however never dealt with it before. I got the LDAP URL and my base but would anyone have a full working example of a login that says yes if authentication was successful and no if it failed. Ive been struggling to site some example online for same reason.

I would really appreciate this.

Comment: There are some questions on this already which might help, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485911/php-ldap-login-problem for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a test but just getting a blank page it dosent seem to have a form to input the login ill keep trying other things. I have the LDAP URL and the BASE DN info `ou=people,dc=cgi,dc=ca` not too sure how im suppose to work that into the code.

Comment: Post some code of what you've done so far.  Usually you would verify the user against LDAP with a DN that looked like this: uid=someuser,ou=people,dc=cgi,dc=ca and a password, using ldap_bind() perhaps with some other parameters depending on your LDAP server.  Probably worth posting the details of your LDAP server too (what type it is, what options it has on, etc).